# PHP fwrite how to select the line?

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm very new to PHP and I'm trying to use fwrite with this code:

```
<?php  
$File = "file.html"; //Load the file
$Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
$Data = $_GET["content"]; //Get the data
fwrite($Handle, $Data); // Write it
print "Data Written"; 
fclose($Handle);  
?>
```

It works perfectly. But the problem is I want to begin writing in the line 15, not in the end of the file.
Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Text data are stored sequentially, you can only start a new file or append to an existing file. A solution may be to read and output up to line 14 and then continue writing your actual data. There are text-based databases which may support arbitrary access to records, but I think that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813457/php-what-is-the-best-way-to-write-data-to-middle-of-file-without-rewriting-file

Comment: How? Full example if possible?

Comment: Be more specific, then you may find someone to help you. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @syck What? What else can i say? You want to know my purpose? No, I don't think so...

Comment: Read file per line into an array using `file` and then prepend your stuff to `$array[14]`. After you're done you `implode` the array back to a string with `PHP_EOL` (line break) and write to disk `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @mucap Your comment is not a technical question, it basically says "Can you write that code for me?" My answer would be: "Thats what I get paid for, make me an offer." =)

Comment: @syck no, that's not, If you're not in a good mood or just don't wan't to help, that's ok.