# How do i take an unwanted character off the end of a file in C?

Tags: c, string, file, structure

So i have some code that will allow the user to write anywhere they want inside a text file, thanks to the answers from [How do I write to a specific line of file in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895672/how-do-i-write-to-a-specific-line-of-file-in-c) , However i have hit a new obstacle, whenever i write back to the file an annoying random character will always appear at the end of the last word, and if it's on the first line a new line is created before it.
I know this has something to do with the file copy but i don't know where, can someone please help?

```
int main()
{
FILE *fp,*fc;
int lineNum;  
int count=0;  
int ch=0;   
int edited=0; 
char t[16];  


fp=fopen("start.txt","r");
fc=fopen("end.txt","w");

if(fp==NULL||fc==NULL)
{
    printf("\nError...cannot open/create files");
    return 1;
}

printf("\nEnter Line Number Which You Want 2 edit: ");
scanf("%d",&lineNum);

while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
{
    if(ch=='\n')  
        count++;
    if(count==lineNum-1 && edited==0)   
    {
        printf("\nEnter input to store at line %d:",lineNum);

        scanf(" %s[^\n]",t); 

        fprintf(fc,"\n%s\n",t); /

        edited=1;  

        while( (ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF )  
        {                           
            if(ch=='\n')
                break;
        }
   }
   else
      fprintf(fc,"%c",ch);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fc);

if(edited==1)
{
    printf("\nCongrates...Error Edited Successfully.");

    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char a;
    system("cls");

    fp1=fopen("end.txt","r");
    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
    puts("This computer is terrible and won't open end");
    exit(1);
    }

    fp2=fopen("start.txt","w");
    if(fp2==NULL)
    {
    puts("Can't open start for some reason...");
    fclose(fp1);
    exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
    a=fgetc(fp1);
    fputc(a,fp2);
    }
    while(a!=EOF);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    getch();
    }


    else
    printf("\nLine Not Found");

  return 0;
  }
```

(Sorry about ident, i'm in a rush)

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    a=fgetc(fp1);
    fputc(a,fp2);
}
while(a!=EOF);
```

A do-while loop evaluates its condition *after* performing the body of the loop. In other words, this loop is writing EOF to the file, which you shouldn't be doing. EOF isn't actually a character, it's just something that gets returned by the OS when it's finished reading a file. I'm not sure what would be the end result of actually writing EOF to a file, but I'd hazard a guess this is what's causing the "annoying random character" you're talking about.

Invert the loop into a normal while loop, as follows, so that you're checking for EOF *before* writing anything:

```
while ((a=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF)
{
    fputc(a,fp2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `do-while` loop like,

```
while((a=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF)
    fputc(a,fp2);
```

I guess it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) As you said *"and if it's on the first line a new line is created before it"*

To solve this problem you have to optimize the use of `fprintf(fc,"\n%s\n",t);` statement.

Replace this  `fprintf(fc,"\n%s\n",t);` with below code.

```
if(count==0)  //if its the first line to edit..
    fprintf(fc,"%s\n",t)   //watch closely,no '\n' before %s,This will copy wihtout creating new line at beginning of line or file.
else 
    fprintf(fc,"\n%s\n",t);
```

2) And Your statement `scanf(" %s[^\n]",t);` will not work properly if you give multiple-words input.***You have tried to use both ScanSet and %s fromat specifer. You should only use any one of them.***

Lets understand with a code snippet:-

`char t[16]="\0";
 scanf(" %s[^\n]",t);  //Assume that you gave input "abc efg" from keyboard
 printf("%s",t);    // This will output only "abc" on moniter.`

You should change it to some thing like this:-

`char t[16]="\0";
scanf(" %15[^\n]",t);//here 15 is  sizeof(array)-1. one left to accomadate '\0'.
printf("%s",t);  //this will successfully output "abc efg" (if given)`