# C- Edit/Update a file(not necessarily in the end). fopen(path, "a+") doesnt work

Tags: c, linux, file, edit

How to edit a file programmatically in linux? It seems a very basic question. I am surprised to see that currently i see no way to do this.

I have a file with me. I wish to edit it.

From man pages, I thought "a+" mode will enable me to edit the file, but it seems that we can only append it in the end of the file, and not use it if we wish to make changes in the initial portions of the file.

I wish to update some information, say a name in the header a custom object i created, how can I do it programmatically?

I tried:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "a+");
fseek(fp, DESIRED_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
fwrite("KOLAVERIDI", 10, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

I thought, fseek would do the job. But, like man pages say

> a+     Open  for  reading  and appending **(writing at end of file)**.

it is always appending at the end of the file(though I seek to a different offset before fwrite()).

So my question basically is how can i Edit/Update a file in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C write in the middle of a binary file without overwriting any existing content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467711/c-write-in-the-middle-of-a-binary-file-without-overwriting-any-existing-content)

Comment: you need to check if `fopen` fails. if it does it will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be able to write in the middle of a file, you need to [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) the file in "extended" read mode, with `"r+"`.

Do note that then writing in the middle of the file will *overwrite* the contents at that position. It will not insert the data you write.

Comment: Oops..!! I always wondered what was the diff between "r+" and "a+". Now it is clear. :)

Comment: This a bit deviates from OP. But what if i wish to insert some data in between a file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the file that you need with

```
fopen(path, "r+");
```

This way you open it to write and read.

Comment: This will truncate the file if it does exist, which would not be a good start for an editing session.

Comment: I corrected it. I'm really sorry, I typed it wrong.