# Can memmove accessing the contents of a FILE* and delete information?

Tags: c, file, memory, memmove

Does memmove work on file pointer data?

I am trying to remove a line from a C file. I am trying to use memmove to make this more efficient than the internet's recommendation to create a duplicate file and overwrite it. I have debugged and I can't figure out why this code isn't working. I am asking for input. The logic is a `for` loop. Inside the loop, I have logic to do a `memmove` but it doesn't seem effective.

```
nt RemoveRow(int   iRowNum)
  {
    char sReplaceLineStart[m_MaxSizeRow]={0};
    char sTemp[m_MaxSizeRow]          ={0};

    size_t RemovalLength = 0;
    GoToBeginningOfFile();
    for(int i =0;i<m_iNumberOfRows;i++)
    {
      if(i == iRowNum)
      {
        // Line to remove
        fgets(m_sRemovalRow,m_MaxSizeRow,pFile);
      }

      if(m_sRemovalRow == NULL)
      {    
        // Were removing the last line
        // just make it null
      memset(m_sRemovalRow,0,sizeof(m_MaxSizeRow));
      }       

      }
      else if(i==iRowNum+1)
      {
        // replace removal line with this.
        RemovalLength+=strlen(sTemp); 
        fgets(sReplaceLineStart, m_MaxSizeRow, pFile);
      }
      else if(i>iRowNum)      {
        // start line to replace with
        RemovalLength+=strlen(sTemp); 
        fgets(sTemp, m_MaxSizeRow, pFile);
      }
      else
      {
        // were trying to get to the removal line
        fgets(m_sCurrentRow, m_MaxSizeRow, pFile);
        printf("(not at del row yet)iRow(%d)<iRowNum(%d) %s\n",
               i,
               m_iNumberOfRows,
               m_sCurrentRow);
      }
    }
   
    
    {  
      memmove(m_sRemovalRow,
              sReplaceLineStart,
              RemovalLength);
    }

    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: No, `memmove()` does not work on "`FILE *` data".  And you are unlikely to be quicker than the internet's recommendation.  You could look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996698 for an example of deleting text in the middle of a file, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467711 for an example of inserting text in the middle of a file, but any solutions are not going to be quicker than copying the file minus the unwanted material.

Comment: Note that when deleting data from the file, you will also need to apply an operation analogous to POSIX [`ftruncate()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html) to remove the trailing data that is no longer wanted.

Comment: Also, you could consider whether using a memory-mapped file would help — you could at least use `memmove()` on the mapped memory, but you'd still need to reduce the length of the file.

Comment: The code isn't complete enough to see what you're trying to do. E.g. there's no declaration for `m_sRemovalRow`. C source files are not normally very big.  Consider using `fread()` to get the whole thing into a buffer. Scan the buffer get the byte offsets of the deleted line's start and end. Then close the file, reopen it for writing, and use two `fwrite()`s to emit first the chunk up to the deleted line and then the chunk after.  This will be simple and fast.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I couldnt find the response to this basic question, maybe im a dumb guy idk. Thanks. I guess now im trying to figure out the best alternative to achieve this, in terms of trying to optimize timing, I have a CSV file of 3million+ lines and I would like to be able to edit it.

Comment: @Gene sorry about that m_sRemovalRow is a char* of a MAX_ROW_SIZE for the class, maybe bad design idk,. Illl try to update that to clarify

Comment: If you are looking for a more efficient solution than writing a new .csv file whenever you make changes to the file, then .csv is not the file format that you should be using. You should rather be using a more efficient file format that is also used by database systems. Instead of programming this yourself, it would probably be simpler to use an existing database system, such as [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

Comment: Besides Lundin's answer which clarifies that you cannot access memory pointed to by a `FILE` pointer, you must also be aware that the content `FILE` structure is not related to the file content itself.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a file in the memory space, you can use [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

`FILE` is a so-called *opaque type*, meaning that the application programmer is purposely locked out of its internals as per design - *private encapsulation*.

Generally one would create an opaque type using the concept of *forward declaration*, like this:

```
// stdio.h
typedef struct FILE FILE;
```

And then inside the private library:

```
// stdio.c - not accessible by the application programmer
struct FILE
{
  // internals
};
```

Since `FILE` was forward declared and we only have access to the header, `FILE` is now an *incomplete type*, meaning we can't declare an instance of that type, access its members nor pass it to `sizeof` etc. We can only access it through the API which does know the internals. Since C allows us to declare a pointer to an incomplete type, the API will use `FILE*` like `fopen` does.

However, the implementation of the standard library isn't *required* to implement `FILE` like this - the option is simply there. So depending on the implementation of the standard library, we may or may not be able to create an instance of a `FILE` objet and perhaps even access its internals. But that's all in the realm of non-standard language extensions and such code would be non-portable.